# Newell's Method to Calculate Plane Equation of Concave Polygon - Improvements?

Tags: math, graphics

3 points are needed to define a plane.  Newell's method is known to fail if the 3 points are chosen around a concave corner - the normal of the resulting plane will point in the direction opposite to the expected one.

Are there any improvements to Newell's method that help in choosing a valid starting point?  Or is there an alternative algorithm that doesn't have this issue?

Comment: "Newell's method is known to fail if the 3 points are chosen around a concave corner": Newell's method does not select three points !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your only interest in the plane is whether a given point is "deeper" or "closer" than it, I suppose you expect the normal of the plane to point towards the viewpoint (or away from it, depending on your convention). So just calculate the dot-product of the normal and the vector from the viewpoint to one of the three points, and look at its sign; if it's positive when you generally expect negative (or vice-versa), then reverse the normal.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this after some Googling for Newell's Plane algorithm. I'm also interested in using the algorithm, but my reading of various literature leaves me thinking that it is the "three point" method that fails on the concave corner case, while Newell's Method will work correctly. Here is the relevant passage:

> This technique, first suggested by Newell (Sutherland *et al.*, 1974),
>   works for concave polygons and polygons containing collinear vertices,
>   as well as for nonplanar polygons, e.g., polygons resulting from
>   perturbed vertex locations...
>
> ---
>
> Newell's method may seem inefficient for planar polygons, since it
>   uses all the vertices of a polygon when, in fact, only three
>   points are needed to define a plane. It should be noted, though, that
>   for arbitrary planar polygons, these three points must be chosen very
>   carefully:
>
> 1. Three points uniquely define a plane if and only if they are not
>      collinear; and
> 2. if the three points are chosen around a "concave" corner, the normal
>      of the resulting plane will point in the direction opposite to the
>      expected one.
>
> Checking for the properties would reduce the efficiency of the
>   three-point method as well as making its coding rather inelegant. A
>   good strategy may be that of using the three-point method for polygons
>   that are already known to be planar and strictly convex (no collinear
>   vertices,) and using Newell's method for the rest.

Source: *Filippo Tampieri. “Newell's Method for Computing the Plane Equation of a Polygon”. In Graphics Gems III, Academic Press, 1992, pp. 231–232.*